# creating xls files with images in ruby (UNIX)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, unix

I am trying to create a xls file which includes charts with Ruby. We run ruby on rails in Unix environment(Debian). We currently use Spreadsheet gem. But this gem doesn't seem to have chart capability. Looks like [Win32ole](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/win32ole/rdoc/WIN32OLE.html) gem is for Windows only. [Axlsx](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) is more what I need but it works with xlsx files. Anyone know a better way of doing this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [writeexcel gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/writeexcel) ([github](https://github.com/cxn03651/writeexcel)) supports xls and [charts](http://writeexcel.web.fc2.com/en/doc_en.html#Example_6).